# como hago para agrupar este array segun letras en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo este array:

```
    var tickets = [

        {numero: 1, letra: 'A'},
        {numero: 2, letra: 'B'},
        {numero: 3, letra: 'C'},
        {numero: 4, letra: 'A'},
        {numero: 5, letra: 'E'},
        {numero: 6, letra: 'E'}

    ] ;
```

y quiero que se agrupe así:

```
var nuevoarreglo = ['A', 'A'];
var nuevoarreglo1 = ['B'];
var nuevoarreglo2 = ['C'];
var nuevoarreglo3 = ['E','E'];
```

osea que cada vez que encuentre la misma letra (sea cualquier letra) lo agrupe en el mismo array. Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español!  Léete [ask] y realiza el [tour] para aprender como funciona este sitio y como formular preguntas que sean aceptadas por la comunidad. En tu caso tu pregunta no es tal, sino una tarea a realizar, pues no has mostrado nada de lo que has hecho, sino lo que quieres hacer. Las preguntas deben tener un [example] para recibir mejor ayuda. Tal como esta ahora puede ser cerrada o recibir votos negativos. Te invito a darle al enlace [edit] para que agreges lo que has hecho hasta ahora y que errores tienes que podamos solucionar.

Answer (score 2):

No hay necesidad de crear una variable nueva por cada sección del arreglo, simplemente puedes tener un arreglo de arreglos.

Usando la función reduce puedes agrupar todos los resultados de la misma letra en una llave ejemplo la llave A contiene un arreglo con todas las repeticiones de A.

Una vez obtienes este objeto puedes iterar por todas sus llaves usando `Object.keys` luego de esto ordenas las keys resultado y mapeas los resultados a un arreglo nuevo que contiene los resultados, acá un ejemplo:

```js
const tickets = [
    { numero: 1, letra: 'A' },
    { numero: 2, letra: 'B' },
    { numero: 3, letra: 'C' },
    { numero: 4, letra: 'A' },
    { numero: 5, letra: 'E' },
    { numero: 6, letra: 'E' }
]

const obj = tickets.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev[curr.letra] ? prev[curr.letra].push(curr.letra) : prev[curr.letra] = [curr.letra]
    return prev
}, {})

const res = Object.keys(obj).sort().map(key => obj[key])
console.log(res)
```